# Methods stored as strings into methods that run

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I had a dictionary like this:

```
dictionary = { "a":function_1(), "b":function_2(), "c":function_3()}
```

But as I don't want all my functions to run when I declare the dictionary, I stored them as strings:

```
dictionary = { "a":"function_1()", "b":"function_2()", "c":"function_3()"}
```

What I wanted to do was to call just one function based on the key that is associated with it:

```
for key,value in dictionary.items():
     if key == something:
          wanted_variable = value
```

If I print wanted_variable now it will return "function_1()", and I want it to be what function_1() returns...

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 4):

Since functions are first class objects, you can pass around references to them without calling them, and call them later:

```
dictionary = {
    "a":function_1,  # No parens here anymore
    "b":function_2,  # ''
    "c":function_3,  # ''
}

for key,value in dictionary.items():
     if key == something:
          # "Calling" parens here, not in the dictionary values
          wanted_variable = value()
```

Alternatively,

```
dictionary = {
    "a":function_1,  # No parens here anymore
    "b":function_2,  # ''
    "c":function_3,  # ''
}

func = dictionary.get(key)
if func:
    wanted_variable = func()
```

Which ends up doing the same thing but without having to loop though the dictionary items.

For more complicated scenarios, when you want to capture an uncalled function but *also* the parameters to that function, there's also [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial)

```
from functools import partial

dictionary = {
    "a":partial(function_1, 123), 
    "b":partial(function_2, 456), 
    "c":partial(function_3, 789),
}

for key,value in dictionary.items():
     if key == something:
          # "Calling" parens here, not in the dictionary values
          # This will actually call, for example, function_1(123).
          wanted_variable = value()
```

For example:

```
from functools import partial

def foo(x):
    print("x is", x)

wrapped_foo = partial(foo, 123)

# Pass wrapped_foo around however you want...
d = {'func': wrapped_foo}

# Call it later
d['func']()   # Prints "foo is 123"
```

Comment: The loop isn't necessary; only one key can match `something`, so just index the dictionary directly.

Comment: @chepner I was focusing on the OP's question but good catch -- I added an alternative under the first block using `dict.get`.

Answer (score 3):

You can store functions without doing a call:

```
dictionary = { "a":function_1, "b":function_2, "c":function_3}  # no ()
```

And after it

```
for key, value in dictionary.items():
    if key == something:
        wanted_variable = value()
```

By the way, there is more efficient way of getting `wanted_variable`:

```
if something in dictionary:
    wanted_variable = dictionary[something]()
```

Comment: You can use "`wanted_variable = dictionary[something]()`" instead of the looped comparison as well

Comment: I can't if `dictionary` doesn't contain `something`

Comment: Then just check if `something` is in the dictionary; no need to iterate through all the keys first. `if something in dictionary: wanted_variable = dictionary[something]()`.

Comment: We were all copying OP's code example, but you're right, I updated my answer

Comment: In the first you checked the dictionary `n` times, in the latest you check it twice, _but you could_ check it once with something like `func = dictionary.get(something); if func: func()`

Answer (score 2):

You need to define dictionary with just function names:

```
dictionary = {"a":function_1, "b":function_2, "c":function_3}
```

If you wrap paranthesis after function name, you call it immediately.

Call the required function matching as:

```
for key, value in dictionary.items():
     if key == 'a':
          wanted_variable = value()
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just store the functions without calling them:

```
dictionary = { "a":function_1, "b":function_2, "c":function_3}
```

Then:

```
for key,value in dictionary.items():
     if key == something:
          wanted_variable = value()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store functions without the () so they won't execute, then you could do:

```
def func1():
   x = "func1"
   print(x)
   return x
def func2():
   x = "func2"
   print(x)
   return x


d = {"a":func1, "b":func2}

wanted_variable = d["a"]()
```

Comment: The loop isn't necessary, either: `wanted_variable = d["a"]()`.

Comment: True, I edited. Thanks @chepner !.

Answer (score 0):

`eval` is a more simpler and actual answer to this question of yours.

```
dictionary = { "a":"function_1()", "b":"function_2()", "c":"function_3()"}

for key, value in dictionary.items():
    if key == something:
        wanted_variable = eval(value)
```

Comment: You don't need `eval` at *all* if you are storing references to the functions in the dictionary.

Comment: I have stored the functions as string in dictionary. Not ref. Wouldnt this work?

Comment: Yeah. Don't do that.

Comment: @chepner it is actually the exact case the question poses. Even though I agree this is not the best approach (see the other answer) and also your comment is valid, I do think this is a valuable and correct answer

Comment: Yep. I got the output as expected as well.

Comment: OK, downvote retracted, but really, don't encourage bad behavior. It's highly likely that the strings were the OP's own choice, not a bad design being forced upon them.

Comment: Thanks. Got it.